# Ifconfig shows only "lo"

Tags: debian, networking, drivers

I've just installed Debian 7.5.0 amd netinst.

Actually I am trying to install the firmware through

```
aptitude install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

When I executed `ifconfig` and `ifconfig -a`, the output indicates only the loopback, but no `eth0` interface. However the Ethernet card and WLAN card are correctly detected, I checked it through `lspci` and both cards appear.

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` by adding `DHCP` but it was in vain.

Comment: Can you provide us with the output of the pretty hardware detection? Please also provide the output of `lsmod`. Why don't you use network-manager? That's usually standard issue these days.

Comment: How to use a network manager?

Comment: It usually has an icon somewhere on your desktop, often found somewhere in the top right or bottom right corner of the screen. It's some applet which lets you manage you rnetwork connections, tell you about available WLANs etc.

Comment: I have installed the standard utilities. So I have not a graphical interface.

Comment: A Debian standard installation does come with a graphical interface these days ... even the standard installer has a graphical interface. You will need to be a lot more precise about your installation and answer the other questions I asked you before anybody can help you. And when you paste the output of `lspci`, please use `lspci -v` to get and post more information.

Comment: I did not get it with ctrl+Alt+F7 @Bananguin

Answer (score 5):

You may have to manually add the interfaces to `/etc/network/interfaces`.  To see what network interfaces your system has detected look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  Any interfaces detected will be identified by `NAME=` Add the interface names to  `/etc/network/interfaces` as such:

```
auto eth1   # eth1 is an example name
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Then use `ifup` to bring up the new interface

```
$ sudo ifup eth1
```

Comment: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules is a new file in my case

Comment: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules is a new file in my case @user 2215151

Comment: @user2215151 what does `dpkg -l | grep -i udev` return?

Comment: ii libudev0:amd64 175-7.2 amd64 libbudev shared library ii udev 175-7.2 amd64 /dev/ and hotplug management deamon @Creek

Comment: Sorry I can not copy the result because I am working on an other pc

Comment: @user2215151 you shouldn't be having these issues after a fresh install, something may have gone wrong during installation.  Verify the NIC is connected, reboot, if interfaces are still not detected I suggest reinstalling the os using a full installation instead of netinst

Comment: actually while installing, the network hardware has not been dected
and then after installation it was detected. I dont know how? please could you provide me with a link of a full version of debian ?

Comment: @user2215151 take your pick [Debian Live CDs](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/)

Comment: @Creek: netinst means the install medium, not the kind of installation you ultimately end up with on your system

Comment: @Bananguin but if he doesn't have a network connection then he can't install the rest of the packages

Comment: I changed the netnist install and I get always the same problem of installation no ethernet card was detected If you know the name of the driver needed by your ethernet card, you can select it from the list

Comment: @user2215151 the machine has a NIC who's drivers are not part of the default drivers that Debain ships with or your NIC may be bad, see [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=58525) post for more info

Comment: So how should I proceed apparently it is a bug @Creek

Comment: when I executed lspci I found both wired and wireless cards

Comment: @user2215151: i posted 7 hours  ago how to proceed. Post the output of lsmod and lspci -v. Without that we can't really help you.

Comment: @Bananguin Hi I used my 3G key and with a pure hazard it connected thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for myself after months of hair pulling.

- Go to update manager at the top click on view.
- Select the kernel version at the bottom of the list which for me was 4.4.0-78 but for some it will be some version above 4.8.
- Click on install.

I still have a `lo` and a `wlan0` showing in `ifconfig` but I now have an `eth0` showing too. I unplugged the WiFi dongle and lo and behold I now have wired inter-net; eureka. With the wireless dongle out of course there is now no `wlan0`.